# Ubuntu Installing Boto error

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, boto

I've installed Python 2.7.9, and I'm trying to install Boto with pip install boto, but I receive this error:

```
    Collecting boto
  Using cached boto-2.36.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: boto

  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 347, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 549, in install
      **kwargs
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in install
      self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 963, in move_wheel_files
      isolated=self.isolated,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 234, in move_wheel_files
      clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 205, in clobber
      os.makedirs(destdir)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
      mkdir(name, mode)
  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto'
```

I'm a first time Linux/Ubuntu user.

Comment: try using `sudo` before your command

Comment: Or better yet, use virtualenv to create a virtual environment for your Python project and then you won't be trying to install packages into the system directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running the command as follows:

```
    sudo pip install boto
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install PIP then install boto library

If you want to use boto v2 then use

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install boto
```

If you want to install boto v3 which is latest and more powerful then use below command

```
pip install boto3
```

If you are using Python 3 and want to use the latest pip then use below commands

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install boto
```